# what will happen when put another project as dependency into maven pom.xml

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I am new to Maven. I have searched online and know how to make one project(name it A) as dependency of another project(name it X). This is done by add a dependency block in pom.xml file of X.

My question is, what really happen behind the scene here? From my limited knowledge I know usually by putting a dependency in pom.xml, it will automatically install a jar for maven project. 
I also know that all dependencies of A will be inherited by X in this case.

I am guessing A will be installed as a jar into X also? Any difference between whether the dependency is a library or my own project which is remote or local?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you mean, but I'll give a shot.

What is going on is the dependency (`A` in your case) and its *transitive* dependencies will be automatically downloaded and installed in your local repository. It won't do anything for project `X` unless you tell it to. It will most certainly **not** do anything to project `A` other than installing it, it is utterly unaware that project `X` is using it.

If you want Maven to install project `X` in your *local* repository you need to `install` it and its dependencies will be implicitly installed in the process. Maven will not install an artifact *inside* another (not sure what you mean by that).

To put it in another way: there are only artifacts. These artifacts have coordinates (`groupId`, `artifactId` and `version`) to be able to locate them, either in the local repository or remotely. Maven takes care of resolving these artifacts (and their dependencies) for you.

Comment: that's what I asked basically. Actually in my description, A is actually dependency of X. But I got your point.

Comment: Ah, ok. Sorry for the confusion. I'll edit my answer shortly to better reflect your question.

Comment: still it would be helpful if you modify your answer to let A be the dependency.